# java get a String from an address outside of the JVM

Tags: java

I'm currently trying to retrieve a char* as a byte[] from an address that comes from a java.nio.LongBuffer, my intention was to find a way of dereferencing this address in order to copy the underlying char* inside my java program but after crawling the web in search of a solution I didn't find any way to do it

Is it even possible ?

Comment: You're trying to do what?

Comment: Java doesn't offer to play with pointers and memory, because it proposes a model that's organized differently. Therefore it only cares that you use that model (you wouldn't be using Java if you didn't want that) and any attempt to play with memory will be extremely counterproductive and frustrating, and will often not make sense at all (you cannot demand to meaningfully represent stuff as a pointer in a data model that's organized about doing differently than with pointers.)